# invoke virtual method 'int android.view.InsetsSource.getType() hava error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.InsetsSource.getType()' on a null object reference
    at android.view.InsetsState.readFromParcel(InsetsState.java:477)
    at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:1263)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:934)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:398)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:96)
```

this error happen at Android Q，how to deal it？

Comment: Is that the entire stacktrace? If so, that's not caused by your own code

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `NullPointerException` relates to method `'intandroid.view.InsetsSource.getType()'` not having a value at runtime.

Make sure your initialized instance has a value.

That error points to that instance being null, this cannot be the case.